# Excel VBA - error on writing array to worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am very much an amateur at VBA so the code will probably not impress. The situation is this:

I have a routine that imports a table of information delimited by a tilde from a text file. I need to pass this to a worksheet on my open file. The problem is that some column elements are strings, others numbers. So I thought a workaround would be to repurpose the values in the first array I have created (BFarr) into smaller arrays that could be dumped in the relevant columns on the sheet.

I started off with one column that just has small integers in it. I ended up with the probably rather odd-looking code below. This works up to a point, in that using `Msgbox` tells me that the correct numbers are turning up in the new array (bfb).

**Why do I only get zeros when I dump the array to the worksheet?**

```
Sub BFudnew()
    Dim x As TextStream
    Dim BFarr(1 To 3000, 1 To 6) As Variant
    Dim bfb(1 To 3000) As Integer

    BFile = Sheets("Data").Range("Data_GAM").Value

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set x = fs.OpenTextFile(BFile)

    y = x.ReadAll

    Z = Split(y, Chr(10))

    For n = 0 To UBound(Z)
        BFsq = BFsq + 1
        A = Split(Z(n), "~")

        For o = 0 To UBound(A)
            BFarr(BFsq, o + 1) = A(o)
        Next o

    Next n

    For n = 1 To 3000
        BFval = Val(BFarr(n, 5))
        BFval = CInt(BFval)
        bfb(n) = BFval
    Next n

    Sheets("Cards").Range("E1:E3000") = bfb

    x.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know it will go into a column, you can simply use a 2D array to start with:

```
Dim bfb(1 To 3000, 1 to 1) As Integer
```

and change this:

```
bfb(n) = BFval
```

to this:

```
bfb(n, 1) = BFval
```

Comment: A very interesting twist. Thanks

Comment: Ticked this one in the end as it is the way I have gone and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to transpose the array before pasting it into worksheet:

```
Sheets("Cards").Range("E1:E3000") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(bfb)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Don't really understand why though.

Comment: 1D arrays are interpreted by VBA as arrays with one row and many columns when it comes to printing. You have selected range `Range("E1:E3000")` to print it - so one column and many rows, and VBA is confused since it got the command to print many columns in a one-column range.
So, original array `bfb` needs to be transponed before printing, in order to have many rows and one column.